# No response on invoke classes inside servlet

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans6.8

### Changed

I'm trying to make a servlet and make use of non-servlet classes to manage database connection and user authorization.I'm using a log file to track when a transaction is been done.My problem is I get no entries when I invoke the below class from the servlet class instead I get result when I call it from a non-servlet class.

```
package api;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.Date;

public class DBase {

   private PrintStream outstream;

    public DBase( )
    {
        try {
            
            File file = new File("log");

            boolean exists = file.exists();
            if (exists) {
                outstream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("log",true));
            } else {
               outstream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(file,true));
            }
            System.setOut(outstream);
            System.setErr(outstream);
            System.out.println("\n" + getDateTime() + "\nInvoker: " + getClass().getName());
            
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
    }

    private String getDateTime() {
      DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
      Date date = new Date();
      return dateFormat.format(date);
   }
}
```

Invoke the class from a non-servlet class gives me entries in the log file.

```
package api;


public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String args[]){    
              DBase dbase = new DBase();
    }
}
```

Here I got nothing.
It's in `package servlets`

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            new api.Test(); //or new api.DBase();
        } finally { 
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

*I'm using Netbeans 6.8 and Tomcat6*

Comment: maybe, you just looking for logfile in a wrong directory. It may be somewhere under directory of your Servlet container.

Answer (score 1):

You don't do anything except instantiate an `api.Test` class and return.

`main` is not executed when you instantiate a class. Either call it, or create a method to call.

The `main` method is meant more as an entry point for an application, not as a general-purpose method. It may be *used* as such, but IMO that is misleading.

Comment: I changed the `api.Test` to `api.DBase` which is a constructor and normally I would expect to see something inside my log file,but I don't. What is IMO?

Comment: @giannosfor "**I** n **M** y **O** pinion" :) It's likely you're not opening the file where you think you are, as Victor said. It will be in your web app's directory somewhere, unless you're deploying from a war file. I'd also recommend writing to it directly, and closing it, like a normal file, rather than setting out/err to it. Or use real logging.

Comment: I guess you are right,where I should place my file so my servlet could reach it?"real logging" meaning?

Comment: @giannosfor You could provide a complete, absolute path. "Real logging" means use a logging framework, like slf4j, log4j, Java's built-in logging, etc.

Comment: OK I'll try it but why I can reach it when I call the DBase class from the Test class and can't when I try to reach it from the Servlet class?Sorry if my question sounds silly I'm beginner in jee.

Comment: I've another question,in my code if log file does not exist I create a new one.I suppose if the file is in a different directory and can't reach it,it creates a new one.Where is it I can't find it